# Application working on one link but not on other

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    // varibles and properties
    DispatcherTimer currentPosition = new DispatcherTimer();

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myMediaElement.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(myMediaElement_MediaOpened);
        myMediaElement.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(myMediaElement_MediaEnded);
        myMediaElement.CurrentStateChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(myMediaElement_CurrentStateChanged);
        currentPosition.Tick += new EventHandler(currentPosition_Tick);

        myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("http://url2.bollywoodmp3.se/murder3/%5BSongs.PK%5D%20Murder%203%20-%2007%20-%20Hum%20Jee%20Lenge%20(Rock%20Version).mp3", UriKind.Absolute);
    }

    void myMediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            currentPosition.Start();
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IsEnabled = false; // play
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[1]).IsEnabled = true;  // pause
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[2]).IsEnabled = true;  // stop
        }
        else if (myMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
            currentPosition.Stop();
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IsEnabled = true; // play
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[1]).IsEnabled = false;  // pause
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[2]).IsEnabled = true;  // stop
        }
        else
        {
            currentPosition.Stop();
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IsEnabled = true; // play
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[1]).IsEnabled = false;  // pause
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[2]).IsEnabled = false;  // stop
        }
    }

    void myMediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myMediaElement.Stop();
    }

    void myMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbVideo.Maximum = (int)myMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
        myMediaElement.Play();
    }

    void currentPosition_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pbVideo.Value = (int)myMediaElement.Position.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myMediaElement.Pause();
    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myMediaElement.Stop();
    }

}
}
```

This is a code written by me to play audio file from internet. At the current link it is playing the file very nicely but I need another file to be played whose link is **"http:// 108 . 166 . 161 . 206 : 8826/;stream.mp3"(without spaces)**. When I replace this link with the given link in the code the application is not playing anything. Can anyone please help me with this problem. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Paste your link (URL) in browser and make sure its working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream you have is a Shoutcast media, this is not an implemented protocol on Windows Phone, but you can use the [Shoutcast MediaStreamSource](http://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com/) from Code plex!